# DVD Drive Not Recognized In Win 10

Tags: windows-10, dvd, cd-drive

I just upgraded my computer from windows 7 to windows 10.  Everything was working good, installed updates etc, sat down to actual use the upgrade today and my DVD Drive is not recognized.

To further baffle me on this, BIOS recognizes DVD drive, and I can choose to Boot From CD.  The kicker, Device Manager does not recognize the DVD Drive nor does Computer Management (to see if it sees the drive and just needs a drive letter assigned).

What do I need to do to get the drive recognized by windows?

**EDIT**
I have also checked event viewer and there are no critical messages or warnings regarding the DVD Drive.

Comment: What's the brand of the DVD drive or model number?

Comment: Use right click menu in Device Manager to scan for hardware changes. (try that two times, one time with an empty dvd tray and one time with a disc in tray) It should at least display as a non-recognized hardware even if it's not compatible.

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ - tried this approach, still not recognizing the drive at all.  kirill2485, will get that info when I can get back to the PC